# Cross Entropy for batch with Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I am attempting to implement an RNN and have output predictions p_y of shape (batch_size, time_points, num_classes). I also have a target_output of shape (batch_size, time_points), where the value at a given index of target_output is an integer denoting the class (a value between 0 and num_classes-1). How can I index p_y with target_output to get the probabilities of the given class I need to compute Cross-Entropy?

I'm not even sure how to do this in numpy. The expression p_y[target_output] does not give the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use advanced indexing (search for "advanced indexing" [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html)). But Theano advanced indexing behaves differently to numpy so knowing how to do this in numpy may not be all that helpful!

Here's a function which does this for my setup, but note that the order of my dimensions differs from yours. I use (time points, batch_size, num_classes). This also assumes you want to use the 1-of-N categorical cross-entropy variant. You may not want sequence length padding either.

```
def categorical_crossentropy_3d(coding_dist, true_dist, lengths):
    # Zero out the false probabilities and sum the remaining true probabilities to remove the third dimension.
    indexes = theano.tensor.arange(coding_dist.shape[2])
    mask = theano.tensor.neq(indexes, true_dist.reshape((true_dist.shape[0], true_dist.shape[1], 1)))
    predicted_probabilities = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(coding_dist[theano.tensor.nonzero(mask)], 0.).sum(axis=2)

    # Pad short sequences with 1's (the pad locations are implicitly correct!)
    indexes = theano.tensor.arange(predicted_probabilities.shape[0]).reshape((predicted_probabilities.shape[0], 1))
    mask = indexes >= lengths
    predicted_probabilities = theano.tensor.set_subtensor(predicted_probabilities[theano.tensor.nonzero(mask)], 1.)

    return -theano.tensor.log(predicted_probabilities)
```